# How to remove a widget a from a list if a quantity is less than 1 in provider package

Tags: flutter, dart

Am using provider package to decrease the quantity of a product in a list of products, I want to remove a product from the list if the quantity is less than 1 below is the code is used to minus quantity by 1

```
 void decreaseQuantity(String productName) {
    _items.update(productName, (value) {
      return CartItem(
          image: value.image,
          price: value.price,
          name: value.name,
          quantity: value.quantity - 1);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: return value.quantity != 0 ? CartItem() : Container(); .. try it might work for you

Comment: I already this is but doesn't work

Comment: Reign’s solution should work fine. Show the code that is using that value.

Comment: onTap: () {
            cart.decreaseQuantity(name);
            print('-');
          },

Comment: Please provide some context for your example code. Maybe even a [mcve].